# What does cordova prepare and then run vs cordova platform add and then run?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-cli

I checked the [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-cli/) but didn't find a clear explanation about when to use those commands:

1. `cordova platform add android && cordova run android`
2. `cordova prepare android && cordova run android`

In the documentations the `run` command does this:

> Run project (including prepare && compile)

`run` is already running `prepare`. So, is there any case where I need the option 2? To me it looks like it doesn't make sense if I'm using `run` after that.

Thank you in advance for your valuable time : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a platform in Cordova does not run the `prepare` command which will run hook scripts.

1. Assuming the android platform is not already added, this will generate the directory `platforms/android` and populate it with a complete standalone Android project. Cordova plugins that have been installed will also be installed into the Android project. `cordova run android` will run `cordova prepare android` followed by `cordova build android`, then proceed to install and run the application. If the android platform is already added Cordova will throw and error.
2. This command is redundant, and, assuming the android platform has already been added, will run `cordova prepare android` twice followed by `cordova build android`, then install and run that application. If the platform is not added Cordova will throw an error.

**Conclusion**

It makes little sense to differentiate between the two command sequences you provided as they seldom need to be executed. You usually only add a platform once, and you can just call `cordova run android` without needing to call `cordova prepare android` before it unless you intend to use `cordova build android` manually (potentially as a signed release) followed by using `adb` or saving/deploying the generated APK without needing to do a full blown run.

Comment: Thank you so much NoodleOfDeath (super cool name by the way), so if I remove plugins and platforms folders the 2 option will be redundant as well, won't be? Because is doing prepare twice, it would be better to use option 1, wouldn't be?

Comment: Correct. If you have no platforms added you can simply use option 1 to add the android platform with plugins, run prepare hook scripts, build the application and then run it for android all in one command line sequence

Answer (score 0):

Regarding option 1, if you already have one android platform, it will fail due to
"cordova platform add android" command and not "cordova run android"

Regarding option 2, even if there is no android platform,it will work

Tried with cordova version = 10

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).